# Session Variable get lost when serving with local-IP but works with localhost

Tags: php, session-variables

My login redirect returns an empty $_SESSION variable when i run my application with the local ip-address: php -S 10.x.x.2:8080. In the tmp file, the session variable is created. P.S
I realize that there are more than 1 session variable been created.

[image]

```
public static function setUser($id)
{
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
}

public static function getUserId()
{
    return empty($_SESSION['user_id']) ? null : (int)$_SESSION['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to use session_regenerate_id() here? have you tried just put session_start() at the beginning of your script?

Comment: Agreed, it's unclear why you don't just use session_start() in the standard way.